# How to have text path by defalut for open windows?

Tags: nautilus

I found the path with button really unconvenient, I would prefer something that can change dynamically, like in Windows. It seems it is not possible, so I changed it to fully text path with the command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences always-use-location-entry true
```

However, this does not apply to the *Open Folder* or *Open File* windows. How to make the change apply here too?

Comment: Just bookmark the folder. And shortcut will be in left pane. The button is on the top bar.

Answer (score 0):

In the File Open dialogs, you cannot have a location bar displayed by default. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to display the path bar in order to enter/paste a file path.

To navigate with the mouse, you need to transverse directories in the file list, or use the left bar to quickly go to a point.

For folders you frequently need, you also create a bookmark. Such bookmark appears in the left pane of the file manager and any file dialog. You can create the bookmark in the File manager with the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. In both the File Manager and file dialogs, you also can bookmark a folder from the right-click menu. The right-click menu is also accessible through the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> while the item is highlighted.

Comment: So, there is no way to display the `Ctrl` + `L` prompt by default?

Comment: See the first sentence in my answer. Please accept the answer if it resolves your question, even if it does not resolve your concern.